# how can I get my game to fullscreen in iPhone 5? using air 4.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, iphone-5

I am making a game in flash IDE using adobe air, want to make it landscape full screen, my stage size is 560x320 but it has unused screen on the sides. Can anyone guide me what is the small thing I am missing, rest full game is completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add in the default image in particular for the iPhone5 you need:

```
Default-568h@2x.png
```

This makes sure your stage is the full area of the screen and not windowed. You can see all the sizes here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000

Comment: i am working on standard resolution, 568x320 hence used Default.png as default image, will switch to the higher resolution now. and get back to you. thanx

Comment: It did the trick. I made a launch image of 1136 x 640 and made a background image of 568x320 also. And now it is working perfect, thanks micheal

Comment: No problems!! I always forget them myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your aspect ratio is not like iPhone (16:10) so if you match your width then graphics will go out of screen vertically. You will have to continue your graphics design on blank area to keep the design continuity.

Still try using,

```
  stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

For more info see 
[stage.displayState](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB)

Comment: i am using it on 568 x 320, i believe this is what required for iphone 5. and already tried displayState, doesn't seem to work for me